# conditions for $\lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha^t f(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} [f(t)]^k$ to hold

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In order to satisfy $\lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha^t f(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} [f(t)]^k$, where $\alpha$ and $k$ are real constants and $f(t)$ is a monotonic non-decreasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, what is the condition that needs to be satisfied? Would this necessarily make $\alpha^t f(t) = [f(t)]^k$ for $\forall t$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $f$ is continuous and both limits are non-zero real numbers, we can write
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha^t f(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} [f(t)]^k \iff\\
\frac{\lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha^t f(t)}{\lim_{t \to \infty} [f(t)]^k} = 1 \iff\\
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{a^t}{[f(t)]^{k-1}} = 1 \iff\\
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{a^{t/(k-1)}}{f(t)} = 1 \iff\\
\lim_{t \to \infty} a^{t/(1-k)}f(t) = 1
$$
It does **not** need to be the case that $a^t f(t) = [f(t)]^k$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$.  In particular: note that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha^t f(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} [f(t)]^k \implies\\
\lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha^t [f(t)g(t)] = \lim_{t \to \infty} [f(t)g(t)]^k
$$
for any $g(t)$ satisfying $\lim_{t \to \infty}g(t) = 1$

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)\ne 0$.

Comment: You seem also to be assuming that the limits are not infinity!

Comment: Fair point, both of you.  Fixed.